# Can we establish a connection directly to Report Server Model (C# Program) like how we do for SQL Database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can we establish a connection directly to Report Server Model (C# Program) like how we do for SQL Database?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450(v=SQL.100).aspx here it talks of establishing a connection, So how we create SQL Connection can we create equally a connection to ReportServerModel? If so please provide the API name. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server Reporting Services exposes the server api as a web service. All the docs for the latest version are [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) Basically, you add a service reference to http://ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx and that will get you to the mangement API for the report server. For the report execution API it is a different endpoint: http://ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah we have used the same Service refrence and tried to use Load Report() and Render method(). So apart from the Web Service is there any other way?